# Airside transit visa in Heathrow airport

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas

I am going to Basel via London with BA on 11-11-2017.
I have a valid UK visa valid from 28-11-2017 for 6 months. I purchased a direct ticket Hyderabad to London and London to Basel with BA.
Both arrival and departure is at Terminal 5. The layover period is 21/2 hours.

Do I require a transit visa?

Comment: UK passports are usually for 10 years. Do you mean you have a visa for six months?

Comment: What is w.e.f?  What kind of UK visa do you have (assuming it is actually a visa rather than a passport)?

Comment: If it is a visa, is it only valid starting on 28-11-2017? Thus the possible need for transit visa?

Comment: What document do you have for Basel? A short-stay Schengen visa, a Long-stay visa or a residence Permit?

Comment: I am from Hyderabad, India I am visiting my daughter in France(Belfort).  Basel is the nearest airport for Belfort.  after sometime I will be visiting MY Sister-in-law in Uk for which I was granted UK tourist visa for 6months.  I have valid short-stay Schengen visa.  My problem is whether I need to apply for airside transit visa for the change of flights (both British Airways flights and in Terminal 5).

Comment: I am an Indian holding Indian Passport.  Further the entire journey is on one single ticket with one PNR Number.

Comment: @VVSSPrasad. Because your trip is in one PNR, but you only have a short-stay visa, you need a UK direct airside transit visa (DATV). Apply **immediately**, because you will need to go to the visa centre to have your fingerprints taken https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/account/register

Answer (score -2):

You seem to indicate that you have what I assume to be a visa to visit the UK with effect from 28th November.

It's not clear from your post whether or not your journey from Heathrow to Basle is on the same ticket as the journey from Hyderabad to Heathrow.

This is a matter on which you're going to have to contact BA, because they won't let you board in Hyderabad unless they're satisfied that you have all the visas which are necessary for your journey.  They'll check that at check-in, or, if you check in online they'll check it at the boarding gate.

Comment: You're having the wrong mindset. Even with separate tickets, OP does not need a visa if holding a Schengen long-stay visa or residence permit. With a short-stay visa, however, assuming OP's Indian, they'll need a DATV (if on one ticket) or Visitor in Transit (if on separate tickets) visa.

Comment: 1.  "You're having the wrong mindset" is not standard English, although it's a mistake which is common in India.  However the right approach should always involve ascertaining what the airline itself will require.

Comment: 2.  As the full details of the OP's nationality are not totally clear, then again the airline is likely to be the easiest way to ensure that the appropriate course is followed regarding visas.  The airline will have to transport back any traveller arriving without visas they should have been in possession of before flying.

Comment: The check-in staff will go by the Timatic database, which states what I wrote. Also I'm Swedish (with a level C2 English certificate to boot), so it's funny that I made an "Indian" mistake xD

Comment: 1.   I did not say the substance of your reply was wrong, but merely recommended the OP checking with the airline.  Neither you nor I know precisely what the airline staff will do -- the most you can properly say is that you would expect the airline staff to check with the same database you have quoted from. Seeking an answer from the airline puts the onus on to the airline to a considerable extent.
2.  I said you made a mistake which is common in India -- that doesn't stop the same mistake being made elsewhere.  The present tense should not be confused with the present-continuous tense.